# Change the Dropdown values based on other dropdown without JavaScript

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns, one with Categories, and one with Sub-categories.
Is it possible to have the Sub-categories dropdown populated only once a Category has been selected in the first dropdown without the use of JavaScript/jQuery? Only using PHP/HTML/CSS.

I'd even be happy to have several hidden pre-populated dropdowns that are shown once a selection is made using CSS if that's at all possible.

Also, any other recommendations would be welcome!

Comment: You can do it using AJAX, there are a lot of tutorials out there (here in SO too)

Comment: I've done it with ajax and jquery, with out javascript it seems hard to get solution. I've done it with javascript if you want let me know :D